# Excel using Replace on Formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of formulas all over different rows and columns in my Excel sheet. Some of the formulas are of the form: `=($B$12-G12)*$B$3*G3`

All I want to do is replace the ")*" with ")^2*". I tried using the Ctrl + F -> Replace section to look in Formulas but for some reason Excel says cannot find a match...All the cells I am trying to replace are of the form:

```
=(Cell1-Cell2)*Cell 3*Cell4
```

I just want to replace that )* by ^2*

What can I do?

This is what I have tried searching:

[image]

Comment: Are you using "? Because when you actually search, you need to omit the ".

Comment: When you use the <ctrl>-F you need "Look In: Formulas" selected, rather than "Look in: Values"

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I am trying to search for the ) then multiplying sign *..............Please look at the example formula I gave in my question as well as the screenshot

Comment: Ah - well the problem there is that '*' is a wildcard. Excel uses it to mean "any character", not "asterisk". Take a look at this article: http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/General/29013.html

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the *Look in* option is set to *Formulas*:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

As per your comment, you must use **tilda** in the *Find* string:

[image]

Comment: I have a * multiplying sign that I am also trying to find....I don't want to replace all the formulas with ) but ones with )* with )^2* meaning square then multiply.

Answer (score 1):

Find and search using:

```
)~*
```

What I was having difficulty with was the * and I found the solution is to just use a ~ and it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In summary of the article I left as a comment (http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/General/29013.html), you need to use ~ [the character to the left of the 1 on a standard English QWERTY keyboard] before *, in order to specifically tell excel that you want to look for an asterisk, not use the asterisk as a wildcard.